# how to assign value to empty rows containing unique value in start of a day in R?

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data frame with date in first row only for each day data. I want to repeat date to all empty rows in between two different dates.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is called "df" and your Date column is called "DATE":

My Solution:

```
library(zoo)
df$DATE <- na.locf(df$DATE)
```

This code fills all NAs,  until next value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```
data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01",NA,NA,NA,"2020-01-02",NA,NA,NA),
                   value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
for(i in 2:nrow(data))  if(is.na(data$date[i])) data$date[i] <- data$date[i - 1]
data
```

...and the output:

```
> data
        date value
1 2020-01-01     1
2 2020-01-01     2
3 2020-01-01     3
4 2020-01-01     4
5 2020-01-02     5
6 2020-01-02     6
7 2020-01-02     7
8 2020-01-02     8
>
```